# How do I flip a card in a list of cards (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I hope you have a good day.
I just want when I click on a card and that card will flip.
But the problem is when I click on one card the all cards flip.

**HTML**
[image: 1]

**TypeScript**

[image: 2]

Comment: Please add your code as text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your `.state` property on the `data` array itself. I believe you wanted to store this state per *card*, but by storing it as a property of the array, then you only have one of them for all the cards.

I propose some changes to your code:

- You can pass the index inside your `cardClicked` handler:

```html
<div class="card" *ngFor="let d of data; let idx=index" (click)="cardClicked(idx)" [@cardFlip]="d.state">
  <!-- rest of the code goes here -->
</div>
```

Chech the template as I changed some stuff there. The `[@cardFlip]` is now bound to `d.state` rather than `data.state`. I am also passing the `idx` as a parameter to the `cardClicked` handler.

- And then your handler becomes this:

```
cardClicked(index: number): void {
  const result = [...this.data];
  const { state } = result[index];
  result[index] = { ...result[index], state: state == 'default' ? 'flipped' : 'default' };
  this.data = result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was great, simple, helpful, and effective. <3

Comment: Nice, I'm glad it helped. Maybe you can also mark it as accepted.